# Best way to copy entire html with control value to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to copy a html section which contains few html input controls, to another section just like a copy of control filled with value which was entered in first section.

thanks in advance

Comment: you need to copy the html to another place in the DOM?

Comment: yes i m doing that but in this case controls value is not showing.

Comment: Ok, please post your code. Let us take a look.

Comment: have you tried $(element).insertAfter(targetElement); ? Or you could show us some code.